# How can I specify DataContractSerializer EmitDefaultValue = false globally through app.config or web.config or some other means?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a very large class library with >100 POCO objects. I need to serialize these objects into XML to transmit to a REST service.

I've been trying to use `DataContractSerializer`, but it outputs XML elements with `i:nil="true"` for any properties that are null. This trips up the REST service to which I'm transmitting XML. Yes, I realize that it shouldn't. The service provider has informed me that correcting the issue will take months. I don't have months to wait for this service to work.

I've been digging through the documentation trying to find a way to suppress these nil objects from being transmitted. I'm aware that I could set the [EmitDefaultValue property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) to false on each individual property of each POCO object. I'm not about to do that for more than 100 objects unless I have no other choice. Furthermore, I don't believe I should be forced to annotate my class library objects with DataContract attributes. I also don't want to mirror my class library with DataContractSurrogates. That is just obscene.

### Question

Surely, there is a configuration option somewhere where I can specify that the default behavior for serialization should be `EmitDefaultValue = false`. I've been unable to find it though. I'm hoping someone else has found it, or has found another global option for suppressing the null properties from the XML.

- Can this be specified in app.config/web.config?
- Or, can it be set on the `DataContractSerializer` instance?

If this doesn't exist, it seems like a HUGE oversight by Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that there is no official way to set this property globally, maybe because it's described as [not recommended practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) in most cases.

But there is workaround. You can define your own `DataMemberAttribute` in `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace with `EmitDefaultValue` set to `false` by default. Put it somewhere in your project. And that's all you have to do. Compiler will give you a warning saying that your type conflict with imported one, but will use your type after all. I took this class from [Microsoft sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/DataMemberAttribute.cs), set `EmitDefaultValue` to `false` and replace exception throw in order check because it was using internal utility class:

```
namespace System.Runtime.Serialization
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class DataMemberAttribute : Attribute
    {
        string name;
        bool isNameSetExplicitly;
        int order = -1;
        bool isRequired;
        bool emitDefaultValue = false;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; isNameSetExplicitly = true; }
        }

        public bool IsNameSetExplicitly
        {
            get { return isNameSetExplicitly; }
        }

        public int Order
        {
            get { return order; }
            set
            {
                if (order < 0)
                    throw new InvalidDataContractException();
                order = value;
            }
        }

        public bool IsRequired
        {
            get { return isRequired; }
            set { isRequired = value; }
        }

        public bool EmitDefaultValue
        {
            get { return emitDefaultValue; }
            set { emitDefaultValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if we take `new Foo()`:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace FooBar
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Foo
    {
        // Warning about type conflict.
        [DataMember]
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It will be serialized by `DataContractSerializer` as:

```
<Foo xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication1"
     xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Comment: Did you check if this solution works for items that have _non-default_ values? Because I don't think it does.. I think this solution just omits every property/field with your new `[DataMember]` attribute because it is not the proper attribute which the framework expects. Therefore the output is always an empty XML. Either that, or I am missing something.